# How to avoid triggering this kind of copy constructor in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I want to create an object in a function and use it outside.

I write the following code under the c++17 standard, it seems ok.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Vector2 {
    Vector2() = default;
    Vector2(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    Vector2(const Vector2 &) = delete;
    Vector2 &operator=(const Vector2 &) = delete;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

Vector2 newVec(int x, int y) {
    return Vector2(x, y);
}

int main() {
    auto v = newVec(1, 2);
    std::cout << v.x * v.y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I switched to c++11 standard, I couldn't compile it.

> note: 'Vector2' has been explicitly marked deleted here
>       Vector2(const Vector2 &) = delete;

I think I constructed a temporary Vector2 object in the newVec function. When return, Vector2 call copy constructor with the temporary variable as the argument. But I have marked copy constructor 'delete', so it can't be compiled.

My question is what is the equivalent code under the C++11 standard?
What did c++17 do to avoid this copy constructor?

Comment: Try adding the move constructor: https://wandbox.org/permlink/sPCkDsNIMN7qJKYS

Comment: I suspect that the term you want to investigate is "copy elision". https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision has a discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What did c++17 do to avoid this copy constructor?

This:

```
auto v = newVec(1, 2);
```

was one of the motivating cases for a language feature called "guaranteed copy elision." The example from [that paper](https://wg21.link/p0135r0):

> ```
> auto x = make(); // error, can't perform the move you didn't want,
>                  // even though compiler would not actually call it
> ```

Before C++17, that expression always copy-initialization. We deduce the type with `auto`, that gives us `Vector2`, and then we're trying to construct a `Vector2` from an rvalue of type `Vector2`. That's the usual process - enumerating constructors, etc. The best match is your copy constructor, which is deleted, hence the whole thing is ill-formed.

Sad face.

In C++17, this is totally different. Initializing from a prvalue of the same type doesn't try to find a constructor at all. There is no copy or move. It just gives you a `Vector2` that is the value of `newVec(1, 2)`, [directly](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1). That's the change here - it's not that in C++17 that copy-initialization works, it's more that it's not even the same kind of initialization anymore.

---

> My question is what is the equivalent code under the C++11 standard?

There is no way at all to construct a non-movable object like this. From the same paper:

> ```
> struct NonMoveable { /* ... */ };
> NonMoveable make() { /* how to make this work without a copy? */ }
> ```

If you want a function like `make()` (`newVec()` in your example) to work, the type has to be, at least, movable. That means either:

- adding a move constructor
- undeleting your copy constructor
- if none of the above is possible, put it on the heap - wrap it in something like `unique_ptr<Vector2>`, which is movable

Or you pass into `make()` your object and have the function populate it internally:

```
void make(NonMoveable&);
```

This ends up being less compose-able, but it works. As written, it requires your type to be default constructible but there are ways around that as well.

Comment: "There is no way at all to construct" I suppose the C++11 way, and what I believe the compiler effectively does, is pass a pointer/reference to the object as a parameter, and then placement new construct it (along with all the needed safety checks)? So not really much of a practical solution.

Comment: @FireLancer Sure, worth adding. I took the very narrow view of "like this" meaning "make()".

Comment: I mostly like this answer, but can you clarify the part that says "There is no way at all to construct a non-movable object like this."?  I show in my own answer how to construct it with no changes to the class.

Answer (score 3):

You are observing [guaranteed copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) in C++17.

On the other hand, C++11 requires that a copy or move constructor is present and accessible even if the compiler ultimately decides to elide its invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either remove the explicit deletion of the copy constructor so that the move constructor gets generated(but so will be the copy constructor) or declare a move constructor like so:

`Vector2(Vector2 &&) = default;`

According to the standard,

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move
>   constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only
>   if
>
> — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
>
> — X does not have a user-declared destructor.

User-declared means either either user-provided (defined by the user), explicitly defaulted (= default) or explicitly deleted (= delete)

On the other hand in C++17, call to a copy/move constructor is omitted due to the reason described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, but not required to omit the copy and move (since C++11) construction of class objects even if the copy/move (since C++11) constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to.
>
> ...
>
> *(Since C++17)* In the initialization of an object, when the source object is a nameless temporary and is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the target object. When the nameless temporary is the operand of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value optimization".
>   (until C++17)
>
> Return value optimization is mandatory and no longer considered as copy elision; see above.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with two small changes:

1. `return {x, y};` from `newVec()`.  This will construct the object just once and not require a copy constructor.
2. `const auto& v` instead of `auto v`.  This will have the same lifetime (but you can't modify it), and doesn't require a copy constructor.

Comment: You forgot the alternative: add a move constructor; then neither (1) nor (2) are necessary.

Comment: 2. auto&& v; makes it modifiable as well.

Comment: @konrad Rudolph, that changes type semantics. I would delete the address-of (&) and new/delete operators for such class to make it as similar to an intermediate-only state-holder as possible.